# нужно написать парсер node.js

Tags: node.js, парсер

нужен парсер, но при написании столкнулся с рядом трудностей
[сам сайт](https://www.marathonbet.ru/su/popular/Football)

1. Сайт Марафон - раздел Футбол. Данные в разделе "Футбол" подгружаются при прокрутке скролла вообще не понимаю как реализовать
2. какую базу использовать, если хочешь сохранить кусок html кода, чтобы потом использовать его?

---

нужны хоть источники для решения этих проблем, а дальше разберусь сам

Comment: простите, если вопрос слишком элементарный, просто хочу разобраться

Comment: У меня нет опыта в парсинге, но т.к. сайт "сложный" (на React.js), то я бы рекомендовал использовать `puppeteer` (примеры использования есть в репе).